# Animations not playing together in a gltf

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I have a project going and it consists of everything sitting still and two animations. I have a character moving and a butterfly moving. However I've been spending countless hours trying to get them to play together when its exported as a gltf or glb. In blender I can move the timeline and the animation plays. My character moves his head and the butterfly flaps its wings. But when exported, im using the standard Microsoft 3d viewer and it only lets me play one or the other. Im trying to get them to play at the same time. Any idea as to what im doing wrong or how to get this to work?[image]

Comment: Try disabling "Group by NLA Track" on the export screen.

Comment: I tried that and I ended up with the same results.

Comment: Upload .blend file.

Comment: Ok, Here it is, https://www.mediafire.com/file/xnuofxgfzfei1fh/Tree_of_life.blend/file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Group By NLA Track = ON***

When this is on, you just need to open the NLA Editor and change the track name from "NLA Track.whatever" to the name you want the animation to have. Give two tracks the same name to make them part of the same glTF animation (ie. they play at the same time).

For example, this is what I did to make your animations play at once.

[image: Tracks renamed "Tree of Life"]

The Action.001 on Armature.002 also get exported (Action on Armature would too if it had any keyframes). You might want to clean those up.

***Group by NLA Tracks = OFF***

This is supposed to export all the active actions as one glTF animation I think (not entirely sure...). If you just assign the actions you want to each object and don't use NLA tracks like this

[image]

it also exports playing at once.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked out just fine! ;)